# Definite integral of $|\sin x|$ over $[0, 10\pi]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to solve this and when I add both of the different signs together I ended by a result of 2, but it's not one of the choices, any help would be appreciated

$$\int_0^{10\pi}\ |\sin x| \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Is it $\sin|x|$ or $|\sin x|$?

Comment: The $x$ in your integration will always be non-negative. Thus it makes no difference to rewrite as $\sin x$

Comment: it's |sin x| sorry about that

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kyl9wwwm1x

Comment: Tbh, I just have memorized that the area of a half-period of $\sin$ or $\cos$ is $2$. With this knowledge, the answer is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
 \lvert \sin x \rvert
$$

[image: sin]

You are making $10$ copies
$$
 \int_{0}^{10\pi} \lvert \sin x \rvert dx = 10 \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x dx = 10 \cdot 2 = 20
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sin $ is negative on $[\pi, 2\pi] \cup [3\pi, 4\pi] \cup\cdots \cup  [9\pi, 10\pi]$ and positive otherwise.  So $$\int_0^{10\pi} |\sin x| \, \mathrm{d}x = 5\int_0^{\pi} \sin x - 5 \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sin x \, \mathrm{d}x $$ by periodicity. But this is $5\cdot 2 - 5\cdot (-2) = 20$.

---

Alternatively, if you're fine with a more intuitive geometrical reasoning then note $|\sin x|$ consists of $10$ identical humps, each of area $\int_0^{\pi} \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x = 2$. So the total area is $20$.

Comment: it's |sin x| though would it make a difference?

Comment: oh okay sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Notice from a quick look on a graph and recalling the period of sine that we have

$$\int_0^{10\pi}|\sin x|\ dx=10\int_0^\pi\sin x\ dx=10(\cos0-\cos\pi)=20$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin (x)|dx=$$
$$\int_0^\pi \sin (x)dx-\int_\pi^{2\pi}\sin (x)dx=$$

$$1+1+1+1=4$$
$$\int_0^{10\pi}|\sin (x)|dx=5\times 4=20$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral

$$\int_0^{10\pi} \sin |x|dx= \int_0^{10\pi} \sin x dx=-\cos(10\pi)-(-\cos(0))=0.$$

On the other hand,

$$\int_0^{10\pi} |\sin x|dx = 10\int_0^\pi \sin (x) dx= 10(1+1)= 20$$